# Mercurial, any way to store just the changes to a codebase and not the entire codebase itself?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

My application has a dependency on a large 3rd party library, over 500 Meg. I get the source for this library as a zip file which is released several times a year. I need to be able to make changes to this codebase, I'd like those changes to be maintained in a Mercurial repository, but I really don't want to have to push a 500 Meg codebase to a remote repository. Firstly it will take ages to upload, it will eat most of my space allowance on the remote server, and it will take ages to pull a fresh copy.

So what I'm wondering is this: is there any way to store in a remote repository just the changes made to a codebase but without pushing the whole codebase itself? So that creating a new build would consist of installing the original codebase from the zip redistributable downloaded from a file server, initializing the original codebase as a Mercurial repository, and then pulling from the remote repository just the changes made to that codebase.

Or is there a completely different way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Slightly tricky way is to store in repository not changesets per se, but results of exporting patches of saving bundles (produced from original changesets). Do you want more details?

Comment: Yes more details please. Also I was wondering whether there was some way of using rebasing to do this.

Comment: Or perhaps [private phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases)?

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial Queues (MQ) is a suggested way to work with changes to third party code.  You may store MQ patches in separate repository.

Here is an example.  Suppose we have third party somelib.zip.  For the first time we:

1. Extract it.
2. Init repository: `hg init` and `hg ci -A -m 'init'`
3. Enable MQ extension.
4. Init MQ: `hg qinit --create-repo`.
5. Hack.
6. Create patch: `hg qnew first-patch`.
7. Commit to patch repository: `hg ci --mq -m 'Create first patch'`

When new version of somelib.zip is released you can unapply all patches with `hg qpop -a`, grab it and apply all patches again with `hg qpush -a`.

Suppose now we want to have somelib.zip at another machine.  Then we repeat steps 1-3 and next:

1. Clone MQ repository: `hg clone  ./.hg/patches
2. Apply all patches with `hg qpush -a`.

The key feature is you have all Mercurial power to work with patch repository.  Many commands have option `--mq` which switch them to work with MQ repository.  For example, you can push commits with `hg push --mq`.

Here is recorded demonstration: http://asciinema.org/a/7245.